# How to make clickable table view and method didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a drop-down list that I implemented using table view:
[image]

[image]

When choosing another floor, information in the center should be substituted.

I have extension:

```
extension DDList: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (Manager.shared()?.location.floor.count)!
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = Manager.shared()?.location.floor[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.textLabel?.font = font
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = Manager.shared()?.location.floor[indexPath.row].name
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let currentItem = currentCell.textLabel!.text
  }
```

I can’t make the functionality of selecting an item from a list in a didSelectRowAt method, please tell me how to do it? So that the selected floor is saved from the top to the middle where at the moment (1-st floor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to do that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let nameOfCurrentItem = Manager.shared()?.location.floor[indexPath.row].name

    //if you use a navigation bar
    self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = nameOfCurrentItem
    //if you use a label
    myLabel.text = nameOfCurrentItem
}
```

If you need an animation:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let nameOfCurrentItem = Manager.shared()?.location.floor[indexPath.row].name

    if let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

            currentCell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            //or any other animation
            //currentCell.alpha = 0.5
        }) { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                currentCell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                //or any other animation
                //currentCell.alpha = 1.0
            }) { (_) in
               //if you use a navigation bar
                self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = nameOfCurrentItem
                //if you use a label
                self.myLabel.text = nameOfCurrentItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also ensure that your tableViewCell and tableView itself are able to be selected in the attributes inspector:

[TableView selection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luGYZ.png)

[TableViewCell selection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je9PH.png)